# Conditional distributions derivation

Tags: self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, gamma-distribution

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given $n$ independent observations $Y_i$ from a Normal$(\theta, \tau^{-1})$ distribution with unknown mean $\theta$ and unknown precision $\tau$, i.e

$$Y_i \approx Normal(\theta, \tau^{-1}) \ , \ i = {1, ..., n}$$

Assume for $\theta$ and $\tau$ the following non-informative priors:

$$\theta \approx  Normal(0,10^6) $$
$$\tau \approx Gamma(0.001,0.001) $$

Given $\textbf{y}$ is the observations $(y_1, ...,y_n)$. Derive two conditional distributions $p(\theta|\tau, y)$ and $p(\tau|\theta, y)$. One should be written as a normal distribution and the other as a Gamma distribution.

I have started by calculating $p(\theta|\tau, y)$ as:

$$ p(\theta|\tau, y) = p(\theta,\tau) \prod^{n}_{i=1} p(y_{i}|\theta, \tau) = \tau^{-1} \overbrace{\tau^{n/2}\exp[\frac{-\tau}{2} \sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i - \theta)^2]}^{L(\theta,\tau;\textbf{y})} \\ =  \tau^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} \exp [-\frac{\tau}{2} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_i - \bar{y} + \bar{y} -\theta)^2] \\ = \tau^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} \exp [-\frac{\tau(n-1)}{2} s^2 -\frac{\tau n}{2}(\bar{y} - \theta)^2 ]   $$

In the last step $s = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_{i} -\bar{y})^2$

I am new to Bayesian, not sure whether this is correct/best way to approach this question. Also I am unsure how could  I find the other conditional distribution as Gamma Distribution.

My attempt at the derivation for the Gamma distribution is:

$$p(\tau|\theta,y) = p(\theta,\tau) p(y_{i}|\tau, \theta) \\ = \tau^{-1} \frac{y^{\theta}}{\Gamma(\theta)} \tau^{\theta -1} \exp^{-y \tau} $$

Thanks.

Comment: @Xian, Sorry I am not very experience and may be confused, for the conditional posterior on $\theta$, I am not sure if it is correct but I assumed the joint prior distribution to be $\tau ^{-1} $ given as $p(\theta|\tau) = p(\theta|\tau)p(\tau)$. Could you please clarify of how to find this joint prior ?

Comment: @Xian for the conditional posterior om $\tau$, so the likelihood becomes $p(y_i|\tau, \theta)  = Exp[\frac{\theta}{2} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (y_{i} - \tau)^2]$ ? I am a bit confused given we are asked to calculate one as a Normal Distribution and the other as a Gamma Distribution hence my choice for the likelihood here. I am very confused at this moment any clarifications are welcomed.

Comment: @Xi'an OK. I still don't understand what is wrong with my joint prior as you have mentioned above and by writing the likelihood exactly the same as for $\theta$ I am not answering the question that requires one to be given as normal and the other as a gamma distribution. Thanks for your pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

For $\theta$,
\begin{align*}
p(\theta|\tau,\textbf{y}) &\propto \overbrace{\tau^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} \exp [-\frac{\tau(n-1)}{2} s^2}^\text{does not depend on $\theta$} -\frac{\tau n}{2}(\bar{y} - \theta)^2 ]\\
&\propto \exp[-\frac{\tau n}{2}(\bar{y} - \theta)^2 ]
\end{align*}
and spot the Normal density in $\theta$

For $\tau$,
\begin{align*}
p(\tau|\theta,\textbf{y}) &\propto p(\theta,\tau|\textbf{y})\\
&\propto \tau^{-1} \underbrace{\tau^{n/2}\exp[\frac{-\tau}{2} \sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i - \theta)^2]}_{L(\theta,\tau;\textbf{y})}
\end{align*}
and spot the Gamma density in $\tau$.

Comment: So my joint prior $p(\theta|\tau)$ and the powers in $\tau$ are correct? I am sorry but I am still confused given the requirement that one of the distros must be a Gamma distribution, they both look like normal distributions and effectively the same to me :/  Sorry for the confusion.